# mvc and mvp design patterns

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, mvp

I am highly confused with mvc and mvp design patterns. Both looks similar for me. can anybody provide me some sample windows application for both the patterns.

i work in dotnet c#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are MVP and MVC and what is the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already some good answers on SO...

See:

[MVP examples for Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185993/winforms-mvp-examples)

[Looking for clean WinForms MVC tutorial for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955973/looking-for-clean-winforms-mvc-tutorial-for-c)

Also some good info may be found here...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406/looking-for-a-mvc-sample-for-winforms