# how to create windows application with mvc

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

hii is it possible to create windows application with mvc

Comment: Have a look at the discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654722/implementing-mvc-with-windows-forms

Comment: It appears that you got quite a few useful links in your previous question about the very same topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698876/how-to-create-windows-application-with-mvc). I would recommend spending some time reading through those links, and then come back with a more specific question if you run into any problems...

Comment: **(Please do not vote to close as dupe; I have merged them together)**  Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5698876/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 1):

MVP (Model-View-Presenter) and MVP-VM (Model-View-Presenter-ViewModel) is used most often with WinForms.

See SO question: [MVP examples for Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185993/winforms-mvp-examples)

Dan Bunea's Blog Post: [Model View Presenter](http://danbunea.blogspot.com/2005/11/model-view-presenter-is-testing_27.html)

Jeremy D. Miller's Blog Post: [A Simple Example of the "Humble Dialog Box"](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/articles/129546.aspx)

Referance: [Mitch Wheat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16076/mitch-wheat)

Answer (score 1):

MVC the pattern: definitely yes! That's platform independent, really.

See some resources:

- [Looking for clean WinForms MVC tutorial for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955973/looking-for-clean-winforms-mvc-tutorial-for-c)
- [Selecting a MVC/MVP Implementation for a Winforms Project](http://rdn-consulting.com/blog/2008/02/01/selecting-a-mvcmvp-implementation-for-a-winforms-project/)
- [Mvc for Winforms - Mapping the View event to the Controller action](http://dhvik.blogspot.com/2008/11/mvc-for-winforms-mapping-view-event-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

Keep only user interface code in the `Form` object(s). Any interaction between the UI and the data or manipulation of the data should go in its own controller class(es). The domain objects or the data itself is the model.

Answer (score 0):

Read the http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/TheHumbleDialogBox.pdf but you may want to look at WPF and MVVM