# How to pass views, controls etc. from main to a user control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, view, user-controls

I need to somehow pass my `tabControl` to my user control, so I can access it from within user control.

User control has a button on click of which I want to change a tab index to different one. When I try to access `tabControl` from my user control it simply can't find it.

Comment: This might yield more information than you're looking for, but you should check out some of the answers to this thread, as some of the concepts explained in the MVC or MVP design patterns will help you figure out how to pass your controls around as needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955973/looking-for-clean-winforms-mvc-tutorial-for-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a method in the user control that will take an instance of a `TabControl`  to otherwise manipulate like this:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl{
    private TabControl _tabControl;

    public MyUserControl() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void AssignTabControl(TabControl tabControl) {
        _tabControl = tabControl;
    }

    private void buttonNextTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // this is merely an example.
        _tabControl.SelectedIndex += 1;
    }
}
```

And now, assuming that you have already added both the user control and the tab control to the containing form, you can supply the tab control instance to otherwise manipulate from the form's  constructor like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form  {
    public MainForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        myUserControl1.AssignTabControl(tabControl1);
    }
}
```

The benefit here opposed to simply supplying the tab control instance via a  constructor is that you can retain designer support. The drawback however, is that you will be subject to an exception if you don't assign the tab control instance.